# ListViewのitemsを検索するには？

Tags: c#

C#でListViewをプログラミングしています。
itemsとsubitemsを登録し、そして、検索するという単純なものです。
検索のロジックで、うまくいかないので、どなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

内容は、検索したい語句（名前）をテキストボックスにに入力し、
検索のボタン（Button-Click）を押すと、もし検索項目（名前）に一致する項目が見つかれば、
見つかった項目にフォーカスが移動し、内容をテキストボックスに表示します。
選択項目数を０にすると、Indexエラーになります。
なので、選択項目数は０以上にしたり、
for loopをみなおしたりしましたが、うまくいきません。

以下にコードを記述しますので、どこに間違いがあるのか、教えて頂けると幸いです。

よろしくおねがいします。

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Name.Text;
    if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {

    var item = ListView1.SelectedItems[0];

    for (int i = 0; i >= ListView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ListView1.Items[0].Text.Contains(Name.Text))
        {
        if (ListView1.FocusedItem != null)
            ListView1.FocusedItem.Focused = false;
        if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;

        ListView1.Items[i].Selected = true;
        }ListView1.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("エラー");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: 関連する部品も含めた画面イメージやどういう表示結果が望ましいとか、items,subitemsに入っているデータの例とか、無くても回答出来る人は居るかもしれませんが、あればより助言・回答が出やすいと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

TextBox の名前が Name？
Form が持つプロパティと同じ名前にしちゃいけません。(^_^;)

選択された項目の中から検索、っていうことでいいでしょうか？

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string name = txtName.Text;
    var items = listView1.SelectedItems;
    if (items.Count == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("検索する範囲を選択してください。");
        return;
    }
    ListViewItem findItem = null;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in items) {
        if (item.Text.Contains(name)) {
            findItem = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (findItem != null) {
        listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
        findItem.Selected = true;
        findItem.Focused = true;
        listView1.Focus();
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("エラー");
    }
}
```